# Docker container cannot connect to azure via MSI

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions

I have an azure function which has this code:

```
run = Run.get_context()
ws = Workspace.from_config('config.json',auth=MsiAuthentication()) if not hasattr(run, 'experiment') else run.experiment.workspace
```

This works when I test the function locally using `func start`

but when I build docker image for the azure function and run the docker, it gives following error:

```
Message: Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly.
      Get Token request returned http error: 400, reason: Bad Request
        InnerException None
        ErrorResponse 
      {
          "error": {
              "message": "Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly.\nGet Token request returned http error: 400, reason: Bad Request"
          }
      }
```

The identity configuration for azure function has the required roles:
[image]

Or, is there any other authentication method that I should use?

Comment: https://faun.pub/running-azure-functions-in-a-docker-container-a-beginners-guide-f921c150eab4 and https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/4857 have you gone through this 2 links

Comment: Yes, but they are of no help.